# Monitorning JVM performance and parameters

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, debian, gnome

i'm testing a java core application, and some times it freezes, i've checked times and time the code with my supervisor (a senior software engineer) and it seems it is quite clean, it is an application with handle an intelligent drawer, so it handle also some mechanic automation parts(i don't know how it is heavy), i'd like to see the JVM parameters if it's possible, i'm running the application on a Linux Debian System that has already been configured for the customer so it has no IDE exc.

Comment: in the jdk package you have the jvisualvm tool, launch it select the process and see what's going on.

Comment: use [visualvm](https://packages.debian.org/sid/visualvm), also, mehthinks this is off-topic

Comment: Use some profiler and monitor the application performance. You should try these on your own first and then ask specific question to SO.

Comment: Though not a code question, it is still a question about _software tools commonly used by programmers_ which is specifically mentioned in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as on-topic, and doesn't fall into any of the subsequent "still off-topic" categories listed (IMHO). How to use jvisualvm or any other tool to find out what parameters a JVM is running with, is a very valid and useful question for many (novice) Java programmers.

Comment: If you just want to know which parameters were passed to the `java` client, like actual classpath, `-Xmx` parameters etc., you can see them using the `ps` UNIX command (`ps aux` or `ps -fea` might work). If you need more details like running threads etc, then use visualvm as others suggested.